# Ошибка при внидрении кнопки Up (setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Код фрагмента:

```
public class sovety_Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sovety, null);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // 28 строка
            getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Ошибка при переходе на фрагмент:

```
01-06 18:43:31.668 9656-9656/com.whitestar.topcar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.whitestar.topcar.sovety_Fragment.onCreateView(sovety_Fragment.java:28)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

код активити:

```
package com.whitestar.topcar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private static FragmentManager mManager;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

       // button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = null;


                    mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }}


    });
    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам надо отобразить стрелку в ActionBar при добавлении этого фрагмента и вы его из активити добавляете, то вы можете просто перенести строку отображения стрелки прямо в активити.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
        mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
            mManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     }
});
```

---

Либо можно попробовать получить доступ к активити и его ActionBar из `onResume()` фрагмента

```
public class sovety_Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sovety, null);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity )getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))0

Comment: иконка отображается но при на нажатии ничего не происходит(((( а нужно что бы или возвращало в предыдущий фрагмент?

Comment: @Андрей, Добавьте в `onOptionsItemsSelected()` обработку нажатия на стрелочку: `if (id == android.R.id.home) { onBackPressed(); return true;  }`

Comment: при использования 2 кода подчеркивает красным getSupportActionBar ((((

Comment: @Андрей, при почёркивании также говорится что именно не так. Так что же?

Comment: cannot resolve method

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете саппорт либку, соответственно Вам надо использовать getSupportActionBar() вместо getActionBar().

Comment: написал, ошибка просто подчеркнуло красным

Comment: А вы вообще от какого класса активити наследуете?

Comment: добавил код активити

Comment: Ну класс ActionBarActivity наследуется от класса AppCompatActivity у которого есть метод [getSupportActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#getSupportActionBar()). Его и надо использовать, если он подсвечивается красным - это глюк IntelliSense, попробуйте пересобрать проект. Задаёте же вы экшн бар через setSupportActionBar, соответственно и получать надо через getSupportActionBar.

Comment: непомогло((.....

Comment: Ну значит у Вас полтергейц завелся, иного объяснения я не вижу(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , помогите плз